# mkdir failed for music. Permission failed in terminal android

Tags: android

I cant create a folder in sdcard directorium what should I do ? i tried with adb shell "mkdir /sdcard/music" as well but still is not working.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Does your app have the permission [`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) specified in your manifest?

Comment: hmm i dont know this, how can i see it?

Comment: in which manifest file i have to look, for ex i have many different manifest files in different projects, so should i look in that one i am working, and how can i give the permission?

Comment: Open your AndroidManifest.xml. Does it include a line that looks like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`?

Comment: See this page for more info on specifying app permissions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

Comment: I putted that line of code in manifest and it doesnt work :s. I also saw the page u recomanded but i dont get anything to make it work.

Comment: It might help if you posted your code and the error you receive.

Comment: I have not yet writen any code, I simply first want to create a folder in sdcard from emulator where i can put musics and read from there. I dont know why i dont have permission from the terminal when i write cd sdcard it works then after that i trie mkdir musics it doesnt

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7891/discussion-between-samuel-and-adamp)

Answer (score 1):

I've had some difficulty with accessing external media from a Toshiba Thrive running 3.2.1 even with the correct permissions. It turns out that they have to be formatted as ExFAT for some odd reason.